# Simulate time passing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I wrote some messaging code that will deliver local push notifications to the user in a few weeks depending on user behavior. I have tested the notifications by setting them to a much shorter fire after time than they will be in the distribution version of the app. However, I would like to test the final time constants with their 'real' values and simulate time running quickly. Is there a way to do this with Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the time on your computer while using the simulator, and it *should* simulate time passing. If you are using a network service to trigger the notification, then you will just have to wait. Also, you could run it on a device, and set the device time.

Comment: How do I set specific time in an iPhone?

Comment: turn off automatic time syncing and set whichever time you like.